# Java ProcessBuilder EXE file not getting inputstream correctly

Tags: java, c++, processbuilder

Hi im building a Java GUI for a c++ program and i'm kinda stuck with the ProcessBuilder that calls my exe file.

I made this little program in C++ just to test this ProcessBuilder thing and see if i could control the I/O streams:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int testInteger;
    int a = 1;
    while (a==1){
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d",&testInteger);  
        if (testInteger == 0){
            printf("Quitting program!");
            return 0;
        }else{
            printf("You entered the number = %d\n",testInteger);
        }         
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

My Java code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./i_o_test");        
        Process process = pb.start();  

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){

            System.out.println(line);
        }   

    }
```

The code doesn't prompt any error and just hangs on the while loop. It does not print anything.
This code works just fine with commands like "echo", so i don't know what im doing wrong here.

(if you guys have a better suggestion for taking control of the i/o streams in a c++ exe process from Java other than ProcessBuilder, im all ears)

Thanks in advance,
Maarc~

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader#readLine()` blocks until a complete line is available, indicated by receiving a newline character.

Your C++ code prints a prompt but without a newline.  This results in `readLine()` not returning, resulting in the behavior you are seeing.  If you want the Java and C++ code to interact you must define a "protocol" to communicate when a message is complete and ready to be acted on.  This can be as simple as a newline, or more complex if your needs are different.  It's really up to you, but if you are dealing with some existing C++ program and want to control it from Java you have to be prepared to deal with it.

For example, if the C++ program prompts without newlines and you can't change that you might have to look for the colon `:` at the end of the prompt string instead. This would mean the Java code cannot use `readLine()` and must process input one character at a time.

Comment: Ok, i tried adding "\n" at the end of each printf but it still doesn't work, keep getting stuck in the while loop. Is that what u meant by prompting with newline?